# Textbox that adds to HTML Page

Tags: html, textbox

I am trying to create a text box that when typed in it automatically adds that text right under the box.  I know it sounds a bit pointless but I really need this and can't figure out how to do this.  I would appreciate all help.  I have come across

```
**HTML**

<input name="name" id="name" />
**jQuery**

$("#name").change(function() {
$("#idOfPElementWhichYouWantToEdit").text($(this).val());
});
```

But it doesn't work for me I've tried it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs as expected (see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTtV4/)).

Some tips for you. When working with DOM elements, make sure that you wrap your jQuery code around the [`DOMReady`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event. You can use the `$(function() {  });` shortcut as follows:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#name").change(function() {
        $("#idOfPElementWhichYouWantToEdit").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

You should also be advised that `change()` is only triggered when the `input` element is blurred (i.e. loses focus). For a 'live' change, consider using [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) as follows:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#name").keyup(function() {
        $("#idOfPElementWhichYouWantToEdit").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

You can see the above in action at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTtV4/1/)

Comment: Okay thanks! How would i implement this on my page, I'm a bit of a noob

Comment: Well, include jQuery and then wrap the above code (of your choice) inside `<script>` tags...

Comment: How do I include jQuery I implemented like this, 
   'code' <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#name").keyup(function() {
          $("#idOfPElementWhichYouWantToEdit").text($(this).val());
  });
 </script>
 <p id="idOfPElementWhichYouWantToEdit"></p>
 <input name="name" id="name" />
 'code'

Comment: You have to include jQuery in your `<head>`.

Comment: I got it! :) @BenM fundmypc.net Now i had another question, If i want that to stay rather than delete when i back space how would i do that ?

Comment: Or how could i make that write to a text file and output that the way this script does?

Comment: That's another question entirely ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `change` event, try the `keyUp` event for the input.

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

The change event is not fired until the input loses focus, so that is why it isn't updating as you go.